# Double summation - How to solve for $\sum_{j=i}^n 1?$

Tags: summation

Could someone please help understand how this can be simplified? I don't understand how to solve/isolate the rightmost summation.

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i}^n 1$$

Comment: Hint: the inner sum contains a sum of $n-(i-1)$ $1’s$ so the sum is $n-(i-1)$.

Comment: What are the pairs $(i,j)?$ They are the pairs  $(i,j)$ with $1\leq i\leq j\leq n,$ each pair occurring exactly once. So you can rewrite the double sum as $$\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^j 1.$$ That might be easier.

Comment: The title has a typo.

Comment: In general, $$\sum_{j=a}^b f(j)=\sum_{k=1}^{b-a+1} f(k+a-1).$$ In this case, when $f(n)=1,$ $$\sum_{k=1}^{b-a+1} 1=b-a+1.$$

Comment: Could you be specific, @DietrichBurde I edited the title, so if there is an error, I can fix it.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The title says "double sum" but hasn't a double sum.

Comment: For what it’s worth, we usually call the “right sum” the “inner sum.”

Comment: @DietrichBurde Not so much a typo as a possible source of confusion - the body makes clear the source of the question is a double sum, even if the question is specifically about an inner (non-double) sum.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews does that summation equality always work... I'm thinking that if our function is not linear, then we might be in trouble... right?

Comment: No, you don’t need $f$ linear. The change of variables is $j=k+(a-1).$ When $j$ goes from $a$ to $b$ $k$ goes from $1$ to $b+1-a.$  @BigBear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i}^n 1
&\stackrel{1.}= \sum_{i=1}^n (n+1-i) \\
&\stackrel{3.}= (n+1)\sum_{i=1}^n 1 - \sum_{i=1}^n i \\
&\stackrel{1., 2.}= (n+1)n - n(n+1)/2 \\
&\stackrel{3.}= n(n+1)/2
\end{align}$$

where

1. $\sum_{i=a}^b 1 = b-a+1$
   provided $b\geqslant a$, i.e. there are $b-a+1$ integers in the set $\{a, a+1, ..., b\}$.
2. $\sum_{i=1}^n i = n(n+1)/2$ are [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).
3. Distributive law.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me alot.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{j=i}^{n}1&=&\underbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}_{n-i+1\text{ times}}\\
&=&n-i+1\\
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=i}^{n}1&=&\sum_{i=1}^{n}n-i+1\\
&=&n(n+1)-\sum_{i=1}^{n}i\\
&=&n(n+1)-\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\\
&=&\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Thank you! This answer helped me alot too.

Comment: You are welcome, no worries :)